# What is the correct way in GJS to define a GObject property for an Array?

Tags: javascript, gobject, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I see in the [GJS GObject overrides](https://github.com/GNOME/gjs/blob/master/modules/overrides/GObject.js) there are definitions for most types that correspond to Javascript types, but how should I define a property for a standard Array of strings? Some options that have occurred to me:

- use TYPE_OBJECT and a GList, but will GJS map this to an Array when I retrieve it?
- use TYPE_OBJECT and a GVariant with an "as" type and unpack it myself
- use TYPE_BOXED and TYPE_ARRAY, but is TYPE_ARRAY comparable to Javascript's Array type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible. Subscribe to https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=727787 to be notified when there is progress on it.

I have successfully used the second option (GVariant with type `as`) in the past. The GList option won't work, since GJS doesn't pay attention to the type of values stored in the GList. The third option I'm not sure about.

Here's a minimal example showing how to use the GVariant option:

```
const GObject = imports.gi.GObject;
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;

const MyClass = GObject.registerClass({
    Properties: {
        'prop': GObject.param_spec_variant('prop', 'Prop', 'Prop',
            new GLib.VariantType('as'), null,
            GObject.ParamFlags.READABLE),
    },
}, class MyClass extends GObject.Object {
    get prop() {
        return new GLib.Variant('as', ['one', 'two']);
    }
});

print(new MyClass().prop.deep_unpack());
```

(If you're not using the new class syntax, it still works in a similar way with the old `Lang.Class`.)

Comment: As a follow up, since I assume you stored the Variant as TYPE_OBJECT, can I assume it's not possible to have a Variant `as` for exporting as a DBus `as` property? There doesn't seem to be a ParamSpec for variants in  `GObject.js` available and even using the stock function seems to choke.

Comment: Interesting, I followed your example but kept getting an error calling the property over DBus `Expected type utf8 for Argument 'strv' but got type 'object'` until I just returned `['one', 'two']` from the getter. That's okay though, now it works internally as well without unpacking a variant everywhere, thanks.